# UDP packets from a field device will not through azure infrastructure to my service

Tags: c#, azure, networking, udp, loxone-miniserver

A field device (Loxone miniserver) is sending measurements in UDP packets to the public adress of an azure VM and to my local machine, both on port 1234(changed for integrity). On my local machine in the same network as the field device I implemented a test receiver in C# which gets the packets correctly.
On an already running application on an azure VM I added the same receiver code as in the local machine and got no UDP packets.
What I already did on the azure management platform:
- Allowed the incoming port 1234 in the network configuration
- Switched off the firewall

For testing I tried following:
- Implemented a UDP sender on the application in the azure VM which sends on broadcast-IP to port 1234 -> this works!
- Added a packet monitor to the network-interface -> here I see both packages, the internal broadcast and the field device

//Receiver-Code reduced to relevant parts

```
class Program{
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        program.Run();
    }

    public void Run(){
        var sync = new LoxoneSyncProcess();
        while(true){
            sync.readUDP();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}


class LoxoneSyncProcess{
    public LoxoneSyncProcess(){
        private UDPSocket c = new UDPSocket();
        c.Client(1234);
    }

    public void readUDP(){
        String buffer = c.getDatBuf();
        Console.WriteLine(buffer);
        //process buffer
    }
}


public class UDPSocket{
    private Socket _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    private const int bufSize = 8 * 1024;
    private State state = new State();
    private EndPoint epFrom = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    private AsyncCallback recv = null;
    private String datBuf = "";

    public class State
    {
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
    }

    public String getDatBuf()
    {
        String temp = datBuf;
        datBuf = "";
        return temp;
    }

    public void Client(int port)
    {
        _socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
        Receive();
    }

    private void Receive()
    {
        _socket.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, bufSize, SocketFlags.None, ref epFrom, recv = (ar) =>
        {
            State so = (State)ar.AsyncState;
            int bytes = _socket.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref epFrom);
            _socket.BeginReceiveFrom(so.buffer, 0, bufSize, SocketFlags.None, ref epFrom, recv, so);
            datBuf += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(so.buffer, 0, bytes);
            //Console.WriteLine("RECV: {0}: {1}, {2}", epFrom.ToString(), bytes, Encoding.ASCII.GetString(so.buffer, 0, bytes));
        }, state);
    }
}
```

The code is working, I receive self sent UDP packets to port 1234 on Broadcast-IP, but not from the field device.
Are there any tables like NAT-configurations needed? Or portforewarding? Does azure support public UDP endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

UDP public Endpoint is supported in Azure. Just wanted to check the size of the UDP payload that you use. If the UDP payload is > 1500 bytes then it will not work.

This is by design at the moment as we do not support fragments to public VIP endpoints right now in the vswitch. The recommendation is for customers to keep UDP datagrams to under 1500. There’s really nothing short term we could do to allow fragments through without code changes – they’re fundamentally not supported in the NAT

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is the mentioning of fragmentation according to Microsoft.
Granted the information is about TCP/IP but MTU obviously affects UDP traffic as well.

> Azure and VM MTU
>
> The default MTU for Azure VMs is 1,500 bytes. The Azure Virtual Network stack >will attempt to fragment a packet at 1,400 bytes.
>
> Note that the Virtual Network stack isn't inherently inefficient because it >fragments packets at 1,400 bytes even though VMs have an MTU of 1,500. A >large percentage of network packets are much smaller than 1,400 or 1,500 >bytes.

Source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-tcpip-performance-tuning